# Process comma delimited CSV file into multiple files with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, csv

Can anyone help point me in the right direction?  Thank you in advance.

I'm looking to make a small application that will process a csv file by outputting the lines into multiple csv files base on a distinct list of values from one of the columns in the array (say Header1) but, I don't know where to begin.  FYI: the list in header one will always change.

I have been able to read the file into an array with this code:

```
[Read From Comma-Delimited Text Files in Visual Basic][1]
```

Now I want to process the data based on the first column.  For example;

INPUT:

```
input.csv

"Header1","Header2","Header3","Header4"
"apple","pie","soda","beer"
"apple","cake","milk","wine"
"pear","pie","soda","beer"
"pear","pie","soda","beer"
"orange","pie","soda","beer"
"orange","pie","soda","beer"
```

OUTPUT:

```
output1.csv

"Header1","Header2","Header3","Header4"
"apple","pie","soda","beer"
"apple","cake","milk","wine"

output2.csv

"Header1","Header2","Header3","Header4"
"pear","pie","soda","beer"
"pear","pie","soda","beer"

output2.csv

"Header1","Header2","Header3","Header4"
"orange","pie","soda","beer"
"orange","pie","soda","beer"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A suitable data structure for holding your data, instead of an array, would be a Dictionary. That makes it quite easy to check if you already have an entry for a particular category (say, "apple" or "pear"). Then you just have to either add a new entry to the dictionary or add to an existing one.

To create the ouput files, you need to iterate over each entry in the dictionary (to separate the files) and then over each entity in the dictionary entry's value (to get the lines in the file).

```
Option Infer On

Imports System.IO
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO

Module Module1

    Sub SeparateCsvToFiles(srcFile As String)

        Dim d As New Dictionary(Of String, List(Of String))
        Dim headers As String()

        Using tfp As New TextFieldParser(srcFile)
            tfp.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True
            tfp.SetDelimiters(",")
            Dim currentRow As String()

            ' Get the headers
            Try
                headers = tfp.ReadFields()
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                Throw New FormatException(String.Format("Could not read header line in ""{0}"".", srcFile))
            End Try

            ' Read the data
            Dim lineNumber As Integer = 1

            While Not tfp.EndOfData
                Try
                    currentRow = tfp.ReadFields()

                    'TODO: Possibly handle the wrong number of entries more gracefully.
                    If currentRow.Count = headers.Count Then
                        ' assume column to sort on is the zeroth one
                        Dim category = currentRow(0)
                        Dim values = String.Join(",", currentRow.Skip(1).Select(Function(s) """" & s & """"))

                        If d.ContainsKey(category) Then
                            d(category).Add(values)
                        Else
                            Dim valuesList As New List(Of String)
                            valuesList.Add(values)
                            d.Add(category, valuesList)
                        End If

                    Else
                        Throw New FormatException(String.Format("Wrong number of entries in line {0} in ""{1}"".", lineNumber, srcFile))
                    End If

                Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.MalformedLineException
                    Throw New FormatException(String.Format("Could not read data line {0} in ""{1}"".", lineNumber, srcFile))
                End Try

                lineNumber += 1

            End While
        End Using

        ' Output the data
        'TODO: Write code to output files to a different directory.
        Dim destDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(srcFile)

        Dim fileNumber As Integer = 1
        Dim headerLine = String.Join(",", headers.Select(Function(s) """" & s & """"))

        'TODO: think up more meaningful names instead of x and y.    
        For Each x In d
            Dim destFile = Path.Combine(destDir, "output" & fileNumber.ToString() & ".csv")

            Using sr As New StreamWriter(destFile)
                sr.WriteLine(headerLine)
                For Each y In x.Value
                    sr.WriteLine(String.Format("""{0}"",{1}", x.Key, y))
                Next
            End Using

            fileNumber += 1

        Next

    End Sub

    Sub Main()
        SeparateCsvToFiles("C:\temp\input.csv")
        Console.WriteLine("Done.")
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the fast reply!  So far this is working great.  I was wondering if there is a way to modify the sr.WriteLine part in case I wanted to selectively write only certain columns.  So, the out could be only Header1, Header3 and/or Header4.

Comment: The line to modify would be `Dim values = String.Join(",", currentRow.Skip(1).Select(Function(s) """" & s & """"))` where it builds the part of the output line which comes after the category. I'm sure you could do it yourself with a For..Next loop.

Comment: @user3599851 Sorry, I forgot to put the @ in my previous comment to make sure you get notified.

Comment: @user3599851 If my proposed answer solved the problem you might want to mark it as the accepted answer, or at least as a useful answer, so that other people can easily see it helped if they come to this thread in the future.

Comment: yes you've been very helpful.. I've just been fighting with you solution..  I couldn't get a For.. Next loop to work but I did get it to work like I wanted by adding something like this..  [ Dim category = currentRow(1) Dim values = """" & currentRow(3) & """,""" & currentRow(4) & """,""" & currentRow(6) & """"

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

- read key column into a list q
- create distinct list of keys dist
- compare values in q against dist and according to the index in dist write row to the file

Example

```
Dim lines As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("input.csv")
Dim q = (From line In lines
                        Let x = line.Split(",")
                        Select x(0)).ToList()
Dim dist = q.Distinct().ToList()

For j As Integer = 1 To dist.Count - 1
    Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open("output" & j & ".csv", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        sw.WriteLine(lines(0))
    End Using
Next

For i As Integer = 1 To q.Count - 1
    Console.WriteLine(q(i))
    Console.WriteLine(dist.IndexOf(q(i)))

    Using sw As New StreamWriter(File.Open("output" & dist.IndexOf(q(i)) & ".csv", FileMode.Append))
        sw.WriteLine(lines(i))
    End Using
Next
```

If key column is not the first one, change its index in x(0)